# matlab: bar, how to change the edge color?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am having trouble to change the bar color, I want it to be white in the middle, and red at the edge. Looking at matlab's description

if I do:

```
bar(y,'FaceColor','w','EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',1)
```

It should give me the above. However, when I actually run it, it only give me white graph.

---

Update: my y is:

```
y=zeros(1,5000); y(3000)=1; y(4000)=1;
```

Using the above, I got....

[image]

Comment: It works for me (Matlab R2010b). Red line, white fill. Have you checked your `x` and `y` values?

Comment: I am using MatlabR2013b. Let me check

Comment: Nope, nothing works, please see my update

Comment: So you have 5000 values most of which are zero?

Comment: @LuisMendo, more hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so many bars, Matlab probably has trouble differentiating edge (`'EdgeColor'`) and fill (`'FaceColor'`) of each. After all, each complete bar is less than a screen pixel.

I suggest you use white edge and colored fill. That works for me. It's as if `'FaceColor'` had precedence over `'EdgeColor'`.

```
bar(y,'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','w','LineWidth',1)
```

Or better yet: replace each bar by a *line*, that is, use [`stem`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html):

```
stem(y,'r','marker','none')
```